# Can you add a new version of an existing Google Doc using the Drive REST API?

Tags: rest, google-drive-api

Wondering if anyone has actually added new versions of docs using the Drive REST API, automating the manual process of right clicking on a Doc in Drive, going to Manage Versions, Upload New Version?  I'm looking to add new versions of a PDF in my case.

The closest I have come to finding the answer via the Drive REST API documentation is here, using File:update:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update

But I don't see in there if it would actually add a new version or not, leaving historical versions in tact.

Thanks in advance for any input or advice,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES, anytime you perform update on a file/folder,

```
 Drive mGOOSvc;
 ...
/****************************************************************
   * update file in GOODrive,  see https://youtu.be/r2dr8_Mxr2M 
   * @param resId  file  id
   * @param titl  new file name (optional)
   * @param mime  new mime type (optional, "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" indicates folder)
   * @param file  new file content (optional)
   * @return      file id  / null on fail
   */
  String update(String resId, String titl, String mime, String desc, java.io.File file){
    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File gFl = null;
    if (mGOOSvc != null  && resId != null) try {
      com.google.api.services.drive.model.File meta = new File();
      if (titl != null) meta.setTitle(titl);
      if (mime != null) meta.setMimeType(mime);
      if (desc != null) meta.setDescription(desc);

      if (file == null)
        gFl = mGOOSvc.files().patch(resId, meta).execute();
      else
        gFl = mGOOSvc.files().update(resId, meta, new FileContent(mime, file)).execute();

    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    return gFl == null ? null : gFl.getId();
  }
```

you will see a new version of the object using drive.google.com ->  Manage versions...

It works in the 'update' branch, I did not test the 'patch' branch, though.

Good Luck